# gettinng error of render flex while using expanded in a column in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting error while having this code
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

My Target is simpel to show listview as expanded having title like 'Showing data 40'

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(child: Text('A')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(child: Text('B')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(child: Text('C')),
        ),
        buildShowListView()

      ],),
    ));
  }

  Widget buildShowListView()
  {
    List<String> data=['1','2','3','4','5'];
    return Column(children: [
      Text('Showing Data ${data.length}'),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return Text('$index');
            }),
      )
    ],);
  }
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with your current code. But, try adding the `shrinkWrap: true` property  to the `Listview.builder`

Comment: No Sir i dont need shrinkWrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints goes down, setting
`Expanded( child: ListView.builder(` is the right thing, but the parent widget 2 nested `Column` widget. For this, you need to wrap inner `Column` with another `Expanded` widget.

Or you can wrap like

```dart
Expanded(child: buildShowListView())
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: Sir..thanks...and i have updated my code and posted a question ...regarding same example....Actually i am learning flutter for 4 days...logically i am bit ok but failing to understand design widgets...specially when pixel error

Comment: I will recommend checking [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout) including above one.

Comment: Actually i learn with examples....reading documents are tough for me

Comment: you will find plenty of example code there.  also you can check cookbook on flutter.dev

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883877/pixel-overflow-while-opening-keyboard-in-flutter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886152/how-to-create-search-screen-with-multiple-selection-in-flutter/76886544#76886544