# pixel overflow while opening keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have solved an issue thanks to stack overflow..but now getting another issue when i open keyboard it shwoing pixel overflow..i wrap column into Singlechild scroll view but not working...

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Center(child: TextField()),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(child: Text('B')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(child: Text('C')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(child: Text('C')),
        ),
        Expanded(child: buildShowListView())

      ],),
    ));
  }

  Widget buildShowListView()
  {

    return Column(children: [
      Text('Showing Data 100'),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return Text('$index');
            }),
      )
    ],);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **shrinkWrap: true**, It will solve your problem

```
              ListView.builder(
               shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return Text('$index');
                }),
```

Comment: but here i want to scroll effect...so dont want to add shrinkwrap true...

Comment: upvoted u...but need it scrollable..shrinkwrap will scroll entire screen....

Comment: What do you think? When start to scroll Listview down to up at that time you want to hide the upper Element and expand Listview?@IMemon

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the screen height is smaller. We can calculate height `Container(height:100*4)=> 400 + 48 + textHeight` is having less height when keyboard is visible. You can use ListView on top widget instead.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(child: Text('A')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(child: Text('B')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(child: Text('C')),
          ),
          buildShowListView(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

And `buildShowListView`

```
Widget buildShowListView() {
    List<String> data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Showing Data ${data.length}'),
        for (var item in data) Text(item),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sir....pls pls check this..i m really stuck i know its very basic but completly failing..can u pls explain bit line..pls  check this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter